# Flutter/Firebase_Auth: a build function returned null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

When i try to run the app it throws an error: `A build function returned null` and crashes. Here is the insterested widget. How is it possible that it returns null ? and how can i fix it ?

```js
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print("user is logged in");
        return HomeScreen();
        
      } else {
        print("user is not logged in");
        return LoginScreen();
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Your return statements are returning out of the lambda function that you passed to `auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen`, which is asynchronous.  You don't have a return statement that affects `build()` itself.

Comment: so what should i do instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your render output depends on something that is loaded asynchronously (such as the authentication state), you should store that in the state of the object:

```
class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  public _WrapperState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      setState(() {
        this.user = user
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (user != null) {
      return HomeScreen();        
    } else {
      return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

I typically prefer writing the `build` like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return (user != null) ? HomeScreen() : LoginScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because onAuthStateChanged returns a stream, you could use a stream builder and make your Wrapper widget StatelessWidget.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        final user = snapshot.data;
        if (user != null) {
          print("user is logged in");
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          print("user is not logged in");
          return LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably user is changed but you don't see it because:

"build" method is called only when you use SetState(),

this means: "refresh the widget"

---

SetState is well explained here:
[Flutter Tutorial for Beginners #16 - Stateful Widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5dkB3Mrxdo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=16)

For FirebaseAuth, I found useful this course
[Flutter & Firebase App Build](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC)