# How to store data of collection from firestore into a list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to store fetch data from firestore into a List which would contain data from all of its documents.

I defined list as :

```
List retrievedData = List();
```

next, on press of button, I wanted to print data in all documents of a specific collection. So, I did this:

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {

          var collectionReferece = await Firestore.instance.collection('insults');
          collectionReferece.getDocuments().then((collectionSnapshot){
            retrievedData = collectionSnapshot.documents.toList();
          });

          print(retrievedData);
        },
```

I am expecting this in console:

```
I/flutter (11351): [{index: 200, title: This is a test 1},{index: 100, title: This is a test 2}]
```

But I get this:

```
I/flutter (11351): [Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot']
```

Also, I just want to store this data in a list or any other variable. Help me out. Thank you.

Edit:

I tried to use `forEach` but it keeps on adding on every press of button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to:

1. retrieve data from firestore
2. add to list
3. create listview.builder

Then you can do the following, first declare the following variables under your `State` class:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isFirstTime = false;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> datas = List<DocumentSnapshot>();
```

Next, create a method called `getData()` which will be referenced in `onPressed`:

```
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getData,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 

  getData() async {
    if (!isFirstTime) {
      QuerySnapshot snap =
          await Firestore.instance.collection("insults").getDocuments();
      isFirstTime = true;
      setState(() {
        datas.addAll(snap.documents);
      });
    }
  }
```

Here on press of the FAB, you will get the data inside the `insults` collection. We use the boolean to only retrieve once per click. Inside the method `dispose` which you override:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    this.isFirstTime = false;
  }
}
```

You can assign `isFirstTime` to `false` again. Then to display the data, You can use the property `body` of `AppBar`, assign it to `Center` widget, and the `Center` widget will contain the `listview`:

```
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: datas.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${datas[index]["index"]}'),
              subtitle: Text('${datas[index]["title"]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Using `listview.builder`, you will have a list in your screen and you dont have to use `forEach` to iterate a list. You just have to use the `get` operator `[]` to be able to get the data inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

Any code that needs access to the data from Firestore, need to be inside the `then`. So:

```
  var collectionReferece = await Firestore.instance.collection('insults');
  collectionReferece.getDocuments().then((collectionSnapshot){
    retrievedData = collectionSnapshot.documents.toList();
    print(retrievedData);
  });
```

But you'll typically want to separate the data loading out of the `build()` method, and use state or `FutureBuilder` to get the data from the database into the rendered output. Some examples of that:

- [Flutter/Firebase_Auth: a build function returned null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416834/flutter-firebase-auth-a-build-function-returned-null/61417292#61417292) for using state
- [How to use one field of firebase to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487131/how-to-use-one-field-of-firebase-to-login/61487872#61487872) for another example of using state
- [how do i call async property in Widget build method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800662/how-do-i-call-async-property-in-widget-build-method) for an example of using a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: You could also argue that since the method are already defined as `async`, then why even use the `then()` method here instead of just `await` the result from `getDocuments()` and set the result from this to `retrievedData` variable.

Comment: @julemand101 I'm actually not sure you can use async properties/methods in `build()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800662/how-do-i-call-async-property-in-widget-build-method

Answer (score 0):

i think its because the .toList() method put those 2 documents just same datatype as "DocumentSnapshot" in the List. try printing this to be sure.

```
print(retrievedData[0]['title']);
```