# Why doesnt my void function update my int variable?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 int variable that I want to update via a void function during an initstate. I tried printing them out and the value is correct but when I try to display them in my container, it still shows 0.

```
int equipmentCount1 = 0;
int equipmentCount2 = 0;
int equipmentCount3 = 0;

 @override
  void initState() {
    getEquipmentCount('Hammer', equipmentCount1);
    getEquipmentCount('Spanner', equipmentCount2);
    getEquipmentCount('Screwdriver', equipmentCount3);
    super.initState();
  }

void getEquipmentCount(String type, int counter) async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Notes')
        .document('CarNotes')
        .collection('PM Overview')
        .document(type)
        .collection(type)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        return counter = snapshot.documents.length;
      });
    });
    print(counter);
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
Text(equipmentCount1),
Text(equipmentCount2),
Text(equipmentCount3),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a callback function so the state can be updated.
Here's an example:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getEquipmentCount('Hammer', (int count) => setState(() { 
      equipmentCount1 = count;
    }));
    // same for the others
    super.initState();
  }

void getEquipmentCount(String type, ValueChanged<int> onCountChanged) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('Notes')
        .document('CarNotes')
        .collection('PM Overview')
        .document(type)
        .collection(type)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
          onCountChanged(snapshot.documents.length);
        });
    });
    print(counter);
  }
```

Also, `await` isn't necessary since you're using `then` on the `Future`, and the function inside `setState` doesn't need to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The value is still 0, because in your method you are only changing the `counter` variable inside the method and not the instance variables `equipmentCount3`. You can create a list to add all the 3 values, and then use that list inside the `build` method:

```
int equipmentCount1 = 0;
int equipmentCount2 = 0;
int equipmentCount3 = 0;
List<int> listOfEquipments = List();

void getEquipmentCount(String type, int counter) async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Notes')
        .document('CarNotes')
        .collection('PM Overview')
        .document(type)
        .collection(type)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        listOfEquipments.add(snapshot.documents.length);
      });
    });
  }
```

To add the `list` to the `build` method check the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548797/7015400